# Angular session object with MVC web Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create and maintain a Session while user is using an app, Angular side is pretty simple, i just can create a service which are going to contain Session data unless user choose to refresh where by data will be lost. like here: [Maintaining Session through Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957450/maintaining-session-through-angular-js)

Since MVC web api is restfull, session will always be null (unless using some hacks like here: [ASP.NET Web API session or something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478244/asp-net-web-api-session-or-something), which i dont want to). Do i have to create a separate session table in DB and maintain it on user loggin/logout? or what would be the angular way to do it right?

Comment: Hi, I have the same question, what did you go for? So it's not possible to keep a session on server side? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, see my other uestion over here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930662/what-is-the-correct-way-of-find-out-if-user-is-logged-in-in-mvc-web-api i enden up using caching with a single cookie client side

Comment: thanks a Lot!! Looks an excellent approach, I will try to implement that and hope I don't get any error :). Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why send the state all the way to the server. Instead you can save it in either window.sessionStorage or window.localStorage if you want things to persist over a browser restart.