# What is the correct way of find out if user is logged in in MVC WEB API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, restful-authentication

I am very confused about this problem. Restfull service make it up to you to decide which way to implement this functionallity.

Ive read multiple articles about this problem, but every article says something different.

For example some people propose sessions, but if you do that Web API is losing its "rest fullness". Other people  suggest cookies.

I don't know if what i am done is actually done right:

On login of user I create a cookie which contains `UserID(Guid)` and on every request which needs user to be logged in I check if this id exists in the database.

Is it secure enough? Or how should I make it more secure? Or do I have to choose completely different way?

Comment: try to google about OAuth, but again it all depends of your API goals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create authentication token on server-side and store it in your database or even in cache. Then send this token with requests from your client application. WebApi should check this token all the time. It's good enough and you have full control over your auth process.

Let me share, how it works for me:

**Object with Auth details:**

```
public class TokenIdentity
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string AuthToken { get; set; }

    public ISocialUser SocialUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Web API Auth Controller:**

```
  public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
        public TokenIdentity Post(
            SocialNetwork socialNetwork,
            string socialUserID,
            [FromUri]string socialAuthToken,
            [FromUri]string deviceRegistrationID = null,
            [FromUri]DeviceType? deviceType = null)
        {
            var socialManager = new SocialManager();

            var user = socialManager.GetSocialUser(socialNetwork, socialUserID, socialAuthToken);

            var tokenIdentity = new AuthCacheManager()
                .Authenticate(
                    user,
                    deviceType,
                    deviceRegistrationID);

            return tokenIdentity;
        }
    }
```

**Auth Cache Manager:**

```
public class AuthCacheManager : AuthManager
    {
        public override TokenIdentity CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                var authToken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["AuthToken"];
                if (authToken == null) return null;

                if (HttpRuntime.Cache[authToken] != null)
                {
                    return (TokenIdentity) HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(authToken);
                }

                return base.CurrentUser;
            }
        }

        public int? CurrentUserID
        {
            get
            {
                if (CurrentUser != null)
                {
                    return CurrentUser.UserID;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        public override TokenIdentity Authenticate(
            ISocialUser socialUser, 
            DeviceType? deviceType = null, 
            string deviceRegistrationID = null)
        {
            if (socialUser == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("socialUser");
            var identity = base.Authenticate(socialUser, deviceType, deviceRegistrationID);

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(
                identity.AuthToken,
                identity,
                null,
                DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
                Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                CacheItemPriority.Default,
                null);

            return identity;
        }
    }
```

**Auth Manager:**

```
 public abstract class AuthManager
    {
        public virtual TokenIdentity CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                var authToken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["AuthToken"];
                if (authToken == null) return null;

                using (var usersRepo = new UsersRepository())
                {
                    var user = usersRepo.GetUserByToken(authToken);

                    if (user == null) return null;

                    return new TokenIdentity
                    {
                        AuthToken = user.AuthToken,
                        SocialUser = user,
                        UserID = user.ID
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual TokenIdentity Authenticate(
            ISocialUser socialUser, 
            DeviceType? deviceType = null, 
            string deviceRegistrationID = null)
        {
            using (var usersRepo = new UsersRepository())
            {
                var user = usersRepo.GetUserBySocialID(socialUser.SocialUserID, socialUser.SocialNetwork);

                user = (user ?? new User()).CopyFrom(socialUser);

                user.AuthToken = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                if (user.ID == default(int))
                {
                    usersRepo.Add(user);
                }

                usersRepo.SaveChanges();

                return new TokenIdentity
                {
                    AuthToken = user.AuthToken,
                    SocialUser = user,
                    UserID = user.ID
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

**Global Action Filter:**

```
public class TokenAuthenticationAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("api/auth"))
        {
            return;
        }

        var authManager = new AuthCacheManager();

        var user = authManager.CurrentUser;

        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        //Updates the authentication
        authManager.Authenticate(user.SocialUser);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax registration:**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new AuthFilterAttribute());
```

The idea is that AuthCacheManager extends AuthManager and decorates it's methods and properties. If there is nothing inside cache then go check database.

**It's an example from real app, but I hope the idea is clear :)**

Comment: Oh, thats a very elegant solution. Ill take it, thanks alot, didnt even thought about using caching :D

Comment: Is caching good solution if you have like 1 milion users? What are the consequences?

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin cache is the best solution when number of users is very high. You can use NoSQL database for caching. I highly recommend Redis or MongoDB. Redis is faster, MongoDB provides more functionality.

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich One last questiomn, if my cache is empty, how can i ask to database if i dont know what to ask for? or i should just still keep my cockie?

Comment: @Timsen every request from the client must pass ID (key/token). Search by this ID in cache and then in database.

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich Oh, and that id you store in Header right?

Comment: Hi, where is the AuthFilterAttribute() ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @VAAA it should be registered inside Global.asax