# Change class in Angular and save it for the session

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cookies, session-cookies, angular-directive

I'm doing my first app in **Angular** and I have a page where everything is *disabled* except for a `button`. The user, when click on it, everything is *enabled* and the content of the title change. 
Simply are two different classes: one that makes everything opaque and not clickable, the other one makes the normal opacity and makes clickable.

Currently I made this demo with **jQuery**, triggering a function on click:

```
function enable() { 
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "Text2"; 
    $("div").removeClass("disabled");
}
```

Now, I want to do it in **Angular**. Actually I've made this:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.Text = 'Text1';
  $scope.disabledClass = "disabled";
  $scope.changeClass = function(){  
      $scope.Text = 'Text2'; //Change text
      $scope.disabledClass = "not-disabled"; //Change class
  };
});
```

Now I have two questions.

1. Is this the best approach?
2. I will manage the app with a user *login* and *password*.
   How can I do so that the class *disabled* is activated by default
   when the user opens for the first time the app, but then remains the class
   *not-disabled* for the whole duration of the session (once that presses the button for enable), that remains even if the user goes on in the pages, and that remains until it closes?

Comment: You could simply bind the logic using the `ng-disabled` directive. `ng-disabled="disabled-variable"`. If the variable evaluates to true, then the element will be disabled. Simply make this `true` on a button click, using `ng-click="{disabled-variable = !disabled-variable}"`.

Comment: And how can I store this for the session?

Comment: You can use the `session.json` URI. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957450/maintaining-session-through-angular-js

Comment: You can't save like session in AngularJS. Though it can be done by cookies or Session variable in modern browsers. For that, in your `ng-click` function store the variable.

Comment: I was also thinking of using $routeProvider. Create two equal html pages but one is clickable and the other not. In practice, they respond to the class "disabled" and "non-disabled." And through $routeProvider I tell them that if he press the button to unlock, it refers to the html page with the unlocked items. What do you think of this approach? Is it possible? Is it too muddled?

Comment: I've solved using ngStorage