# How to implement the session timeout in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, session, timeout

How to implement the session timeout in angular js?

My requirement is session timeout.. while session expired it will prompt a message as "session expire. do you want to  continue? with  yes or no option.." if yes, same session will continue. If no, to get an message as "the session has expired. Please close the window."

Comment: this might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957450/maintaining-session-through-angular-js

Comment: can you please post your progress so far. SO is not really a "please write some code for me " platform

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `function` that is executed after interval. That way you can check if user is logged in or not.
Execute that function when your user lands on your site to check of the timeout.