# How to hide the contents of other page untill login using angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i have 2 pages.. in one one page i have header section with signIn, and in other page i have top header contents and SignUp form.
1. the top header contents must be hidden. Once i signin the topheader must be shown.
2. if i havent signed in, then the signup form must be shown, once sign IN, the signUp form must be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sessions.

Here is a kind of snippet for you:

```
app.factory('Session', function($http) {
 var Session = {
    data: {},
    saveSession: function() { /* save session data to db */ },
updateSession: function() { 
  /* load data from db */
  $http.get('session.json').then(function(r) { return Session.data = r.data;});
}
};
Session.updateSession();
 return Session; 
});
```

Here is Plunker example how you can use that: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fg3uF4ukl5p88Z0AeQqU?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for response, i need in angular2.. how can i do that.. it is from different pages

Comment: See the above code. May be this link will be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957450/maintaining-session-through-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

use local storage to set the values like

```
localStorage.setItem("yourvariable", 'true');
```

get this variable on every page load to check if it true or no. like

```
localStorage.getItem("yourvariable");
```

you can also update the local storage value like

```
var updatevalue= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yourvariable"));

updatevalue = "false";

localStorage.setItem("yourvariable",JSON.stringify(updatevalue));
```

Comment: thanks for response, but how can i fetch data from one page to other

Comment: you can use local storage for this if you want to get this from multiple pages.

Comment: in Ts i had used localstorage, do i need to access the same?

Comment: check my updated answer you need to store a new variable like setlogin in local storage and check every time if it true. you can also update local storage where you want to make it false.

Comment: so, i give localStorage.setItem('yourvariable', true); in Ts and in other page html what should i give?

Comment: you need to assign this to a variable like setlogin = localStorage.setItem('yourvariable', true); and to get this value you need something like getLogin  = localStorage.getItem('yourvariable'); and in HtML check *ngIf = "getLogin == true"

Comment: login(email,password) {
    this.localSt.store('boundValue', email);
    var data = {
      email:email,
      password:password
    };
    this.ApiService
        .login(data)
        .subscribe(
          user => {
            this.signIn.hide();
            localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'true') 
            this.toasterService.pop('success', 'SignIn Successfull');
            this.myFav = true;
          },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165059/discussion-between-hrishikesh-kale-and-bhrungarajni).