# How to stay logged in? Spring Security with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

I have recently cloned a sample project on GitHub [jwt-spring-boot-security-angularjs](https://github.com/techforumist/jwt-spring-boot-security-angularjs)

I understood most of parts of it but there's something I don't really get that is when I refresh my browser I get logged out

I tried adding using session storage

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = $sessionStorage.loginSession;
```

I put this line of code to the home.js which run at initialization but still ends up logged out when I refreshed the browser

any ideas? will be helpful if its explained thoroughly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining Session through Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957450/maintaining-session-through-angular-js)

Comment: Hello thanks for replying but I don't think it's gonna work?